# Importing a whole folder of python files

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

In the current python program I'm working on, I need to access a lot of stored data. I store it in the form of a bunch of dictionaries, each in their own file. Each file has a single command: giveArchive(). So to access one of the files, I use:

```
import fileName
return fileName.giveArchive()
```

And this has worked well so far, but as the number of files I need grows, I want to streamline this a little bit. I'd like to store all of these files in the same folder, and that folder in the same directory as my main file. Is there some way I can import every file in a folder? And if I do, how can I use 'giveArchive()' from specific files in it?

Comment: Save the dicts as json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
from folder.subfolder.deepersubfolder import filename
return filename.giveArchive()
```

this assumes `folder` can be accessed from the directory your script is running in

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, this works. Is there some way to just import everything in the folder? As opposed to having to do this for every filename?

Comment: Firstly, if this answered your question it would be great if you could click the check mark by the post (that's how you accept an answer so the thread closes). To answer your second question, I believe that if you were to say `from folder.subfolder.deepersubfolder import *` it would import all the files from that folder. Take care when importing `*` though, as this can give you unexpected global variables...

Comment: Ah, apologies. I'm new to this site. So I tried using this, but now when I refer to a specific file in the folder, it says it isn't recognized. Ie, fileName.giveArchive fails now

Comment: No worries! I think after looking into it a bit that `import *`  is only supposed to import things from Python files specifically. I think it may be best to stick with the answer from the post above...Alternatively you can look into making databases in formats such as `.json` which could be useful for you. Or use the `os` module for its modules like `os.walk()` or `os.listdir()` which could be useful for you as well depending on your end goal

Comment: How does this solve the problem in the question at all? This just imports from one file, not all files. You'd have to hard-code all the filenames, since the argument to `import` isn't a variable that's expanded.

Comment: @Barmar well instead of `import filename` you might be able to put `import *`, no? I haven't set up a project like that myself but it sounds reasonable.