# How do you get all the classes in another package so they can be instantiated in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import, global

I read the question ["Importing a whole folder of python files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699587/importing-a-whole-folder-of-python-files), but it does not include a way to do it without one import per file.

Beside the requirement of avoiding several imports, it is required that the number of classes have nothing to do with the amount of code written. I also want to avoid "from source import *" from being in the code, but am not against it.

I have tried this.

```
from system.models import *
```

but that results in

> ```
> model = globals()[class_name](labels.size()[:-1], labels.size()[-1])
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I have also tried this

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, r'../system/models')
```

but that results in the globals not containing the classes.

The ultimate goal is, given a folder designated as a python package, to get all the classes in the python files contained in that package.

Comment: Why not just `import system.models as sys_mods`? Then you can do `getattr(sys_mods, class_name)`. Do the class names even need to be dynamic though?

Comment: I can't find the question "Importing a whole folder of python files". Can you add a link?

Comment: You can use `importlib` to import dynamically.

Comment: _but that results in `'module' object is not callable`_ Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Given the error message you got... are you actually trying to get the classes defined in all the *submodules* of a package, rather than the classes in the package namespace itself?

Comment: @user2357112 That is correct. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That does not fetch the class names dynamically

Comment: @Barmar I added the link

Comment: @InSync I want to loop through all the classes contained in the python files of the package so I can instantiate all of them at once dynamically.

Comment: @InSync It was an XY problem. I was using class names directly previously and it turns out that using class objects is good.

Comment: Despite being accepted, the answer in the linked question doesn't actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to load the class object dynamically with the following code.

```py
    classes = []
    package = models
    for importer, modname, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__):
        module = importlib.import_module(f"{package.__name__}.{modname}")
        for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
            if inspect.isclass(obj) and obj.__module__ == module.__name__:
                classes.append(obj)
```

Then take any class object from classes and you can create an instance of it like this.

```py
        new_object = class_object()
```